# how to get the text between 2 words in postgresql?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a column criteria that includes values like

```
include criteria:

-sss

-ssrgrtg

-regrtg

exclude criteria:

-ssf

-fff
```

I want to get the text between include criteria to exclude criteria saved in one variable and text after exclude criteria to save under another variable in postgresql.

query like:
select ... as criteria1, ... as criteria2, criteria from temp;

Comment: cam you show us desired result from this example data? also there is possible multiple  `include criteria` and `exclude criteria` in  one column? if yes, also show desired output for this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

substring(lower(criteria) from 'include criteria(.+)exclude criteria') gave the substring

substring(lower(criteria) from 'exclude criteria(.+)')  gave the 2nd substring